# Mouse wheel control in jQuery UI Slider scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mousewheel, jquery-ui-slider

I have modified jQuery UI Slider Scrollbar for my needs. There is the original version of slider http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406899/bind-mouse-wheel-to-jquery-ui-slider)

I have html

```
<div class="ui-slide-range">
    <div id="sliderContent">        
        <div class="viewer ui-corner-all">
            <div class="content-conveyor ui-helper-clearfix">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/item4.jpg" height="152" width="205" alt="">   
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div id="slider"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And jQuery code

```
$(function() {

//vars
var conveyor = $(".content-conveyor", $("#sliderContent")),
item = $(".item", $("#sliderContent"));

//set length of conveyor
conveyor.css("width", item.length * parseInt(item.css("width")));

    //config
    var sliderOpts = {
  max: (item.length * parseInt(item.css("width"))) - parseInt($(".viewer", $("#sliderContent")).css("width")),
      slide: function(e, ui) { 
        conveyor.css("left", "-" + ui.value + "px");
      }
    };

    //create slider
    $("#slider").slider(sliderOpts);
  });

$( "#slider" ).slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 1,
            slide: function() {
                update();
            }
});
```

How can I add mousewheel action for this slider? I used search, and find a lot of questions, but answers dont help me. Here are links to some questions. [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406899/bind-mouse-wheel-to-jquery-ui-slider) [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722949/ui-slider-mousewheel)

I've been working on this for a whole day, I can not in any way solve the problem, please help.

The JsFiddle link is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/552zT/)

Comment: Im a bit against changing jQuery code. It will really get in the way when you want to update your jQuery version for bug fixes and all that. A scrolling div without the custom scrollbar is not hard work anyway as the scrolling can be done by the DOM. Consider doing this bit without using jQuery plugins.

Comment: This may be useful http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml

Comment: @woverton there is just such a plugin mousewheel.js http://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/ I want to make it work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/knY4N/) jquery ui slider with mousewheel support using [jquery mousewheel plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel)**

code:

```
$(function() {
    var value;
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            value = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
            $('#slider_val').html(value);
        }
    });

    value = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
    $('#slider_val').html(value);

    $('#slider').on('mousewheel', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        value = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );

        //console.log(event.deltaX, event.deltaY, event.deltaFactor);

        //Mousewheel Scrolled up
        if(event.deltaY == -1){
            //alert("scrolled down");
            value = value+1;
            $( "#slider" ).slider("value", value);
            $('#slider_val').html(value);
        }
        //Mousewheel Scrolled down
        else if(event.deltaY == 1){
            //alert("scrolled up");
            value = value-1;
            $( "#slider" ).slider( "value", value );
            $('#slider_val').html(value);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: On which browser are you checking ?

Comment: Test it in firefox ! It works in that ! I don't have chrome lastes version so haven't tested with that !

Comment: The reason for not working on chrome is that in fiddle the mousewheel plugin file is not included because of some error, so in you local you will have to download that file from the live link to your local and include it accordingly and then it will work ! Try it and let me know if you have any problem !

Comment: I found the problem in your code. It was link to script) See an update http://jsfiddle.net/knY4N/1/ . Thanks!

Comment: That is what I was trying to say in my previous comment ! The code works great if the plugin scrip is included properly ! Please consider accepting the answer !

Comment: However, I cant bind it to my html markup( I dont know why(

Answer (score 1):

( **WORKING version** of this post )

1. you forgot "move" content (div with class "scroll-content" in [slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll))
2. changed ( scroll down = look new photos)
3. fixed values for content and slider

   ```
   setTimeout( sizeScrollbar, 10 );//safari wants a timeout

   $( ".scroll-pane" ).mousewheel(function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {    
       event.preventDefault();

       var 
           value = scrollbar.slider( "option", "value" ),  // Get position of slider (% of 100%)
           value2 = scrollbar.slider( "option", "value" ), // Get position of slider (% of 100%)

           scrollSpeed = 75,
           widthFull = 2000;   // variable (for help: getimagesize, widthNow += ImgWidth, widthFull += widthNow)
           scrollLimit = (-1) * widthFull + innerWidth;    // innerWidth - browser's width


       value = (-1) * (value / 100) * widthFull  + delta * scrollSpeed;
       value > 0 && (value = 0);                           // 'left' limit
       value < scrollLimit && (value = scrollLimit);       // 'right' limit

       $(".scroll-content").css('margin-left', value );    // Setter for content


       value2 += -1 * delta * ( 100 / (widthFull / scrollSpeed) ); //100% / (count of times want to scroll)
       value2 < 0 && (value2 = 0);
       value2 > 100 && (value2 = 100);

       scrollbar.slider( "option", "value", value2 );   // Setter for slider
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem, may be useful to someone.

```
setTimeout( sizeScrollbar, 10 );//safari wants a timeout
$( ".scroll-pane" ).mousewheel(function (event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {event.preventDefault();
   var value = scrollbar.slider( "option", "value" );
   value -= delta;
   value > 100 && (value = 100);
   value < 0 && (value = 0);
scrollbar.slider( "option", "value", value );
        });

 });
```

Just needed to add wrapper blocks to my code. Thank all.

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/GEfMG/)